# why Image is getting cropped in IE alone?

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, cross-browser

```
<img id="DisplayImage" ng-src={{model.picSmall}} class="img-circle" style=" vertical-align:middle; padding-top:4px;">
```

In other browsers it is working fine but not in IE. I have included DOCTYPE,but its not getting cropped.

Comment: what version of IE are you running?

Comment: Im using latest version IE 11@Chris